# file-get-contents : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

In my application I need to open one file to get the contents present in that.

for that I used `file_get_contents()`

```
$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/web/application/logs/GP_CONFIG/GPConfig_1_1_142604514158.dat');
```

But this causes an error

> Severity: Warning  --> file_get_contents(/var/www/Web/application/logs/GP_CONFIG/GPConfig_1_1_142604514158.dat) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Why this error is occurring? how to fix this?

Comment: check the directory name and file name it's case sensitive

Comment: the same file is exist in directory

Comment: Maybe permissions/user?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

if the file actually exists then it is probably a rights/ownership issue.

```
$ chmod 775 /var/www/Web/application/logs/GP_CONFIG/GPConfig_1_1_142604514158.dat
```

and check the ownership of the file 
`ls -l /var/www/Web/application/logs/GP_CONFIG/GPConfig_1_1_142604514158.dat`
.  But actually, it is more likely you made a typo in the filename

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507